# AT Command to send Sms with sender

Tags: c#, sms

Is there a way to suggest to the SMSC the name of the sender/number of an sms?
Someone in stackoverflow said it is not possible to set the sender number/name.
But can I still use an AT command to suggest the SMSC the number/name I want to use?
I know there are some sms gateway that allow to choose sender's name.
eg. sms.aruba.it

```
this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT" + (char)(13));
Thread.Sleep(4);
this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + (char)(13));
**this.SerialPort.Writeline("AT TO SUGGEST SENDER NAME/NUMBER")**
Thread.Sleep(5);
this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + cellNo + "\"");
Thread.Sleep(10);
this.serialPort.WriteLine(">" + messages + (char)(26));
```

Comment: Short answer : No its not possible.

Comment: if it is not possible, why sms gateway can?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11620273/799558