# Android SMS originating address issue

Tags: android, sms

I have an app published that handles SMS messages. I have received some feedback about users wanting the app to handle SMS messages that come from a sender with letters instead of a plain old phone number. That is, if I understand it right, they sometimes receive messages not only from a sender number like "123-456-1234" but also from a sender like "LETTERED". I have never seen this before. In the emulator I tried emulating an SMS with such a sender using a command like `sms send TESTSENDER MessageContent` and the emulator says that it only accepts numbers `+[0-9]*`. Does any one else have any idea of what my users are talking about?

Comment: AxiomaticNexus: Did you ever figure out how to do this on the emulator?

Comment: @hopia The emulator as of today still does not support these alphanumeric originating addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users are talking about companies that change their Sender ID to an alphanumeric number. Some examples of this are when your carrier texts you (i.e. my carrier texts me from 'Vodafone'), or when my dentist texts me about my upcoming appointment from 'DENTIST'.

Take a look at this answer for some info about how they do it: [How do some SMS messages transmit the senders name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605323/how-do-some-sms-messages-transmit-the-senders-name)

If your app sorts texts or something similar, I imagine that you could just filter them the same way you would a standard telephone number.

Comment: I have never seen such a thing in the United States. I guess this system only applies to some other countries.

Comment: Also, is there a way to emulate an incoming SMS like this in the Android emulator?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert, but I don't believe that you can simulate texts from alphanumeric senders.